# Как правильно сделать GET запрос с body?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как правильно сделать get запрос с body  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    getQuestionWithoutTag(page, size, id) {
        let query = '/api/question/withTags?page=' + page + '&size=' + size;
        return fetch(query,{body : JSON.stringify(id)})
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json()
                } else {
                    let error = new Error();
                    error.response = response.text();
                    throw error;
                }
            }).catch(error => error.response.then(message => console.log(message)));
    }
```

Comment: никак не получится

Comment: и как быть ? :)

Comment: делайте пост запрос или передавайте данные через заголовок либо путь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По стандартам get запрос не может иметь тела. Формат get запроса не предполагает тела. Если вам необходимо тело то используйте post или put. А если get то передавайте данные в заголовке либо пути.

Рекомедую ознакомиться с информацией [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) или [здесь](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/http-get-delete-request-body-guidelines/)

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Comment: Спасибо, не подскажите как правильно передать body `body : JSON.stringify([id])` так не получается

Comment: body: [id] не прошло? Вы указываете что там json зачем вы в строку ее переводите?

Comment: спасибо) попробую так, не судите строго думал так правильно